# Convert nvarchar to datetime sql server

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I try to convert `2016/07/15` (nvarchar format)  to this `datetime` format  `2016-07-15 00:00:00` in sql server. But i need the time part to be the current time. can any one help ?

This is my sp:

```
declare @DateTime varchar(50)
set @DateTime = '2016/07/15'
select convert(varchar, cast(@DateTime as datetime), 120)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
declare @DateTime varchar(50)
set @DateTime = CONCAT('2016/07/15' , ' ', CONVERT(TIME, GETDATE()))

select @DateTime
select convert(varchar, cast(@DateTime as datetime2(7)), 120)
```

Or replace the `CONCAT` with:

```
set @DateTime = '2016/07/15' + ' ' +  CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), CONVERT(TIME, GETDATE()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

Just concat time with your output

```
declare @DateTime varchar(50)
set @DateTime = '2016/07/15'
select convert(varchar, cast(@DateTime as datetime), 101) + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar, getdate(),108)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
DECLARE @DateTime VARCHAR(50)

SET @DateTime = '2016/07/15'

SELECT DATEADD(day, 0, DATEDIFF(day, 0, @DateTime)) + DATEADD(day, 0 - DATEDIFF(day, 0, getdate()), getdate())
```

Comment: i have try this and it works. but i don't know how it work. can you explain this, please ?